# Proving $f_n\to f$a.e implies $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing

> **Exercise**: Let $(f)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions such that $f_n\to f$a.e(almost everyehere) and there exists $g$ integrable such that $|f_n|\leqslant g$a.e
>   for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Prove that $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly.

I think I can apply the following theorem:

> **Ergoroff Theorem:**
>   Consider $E\in\mathscr{F}$(sigma-algebra), and $E\in\Omega$ defined on a measure space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$. Suppose $\mu(E)<\infty$, and $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $E\to\mathbb{R}$ which are finite almost everywhere and converge almost everywhere to a function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ which is also finite almost everywhere. Then $f_n\to f$ almost uniformly in $E$.

I now that $f_n\to f$ a.e so $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\forall x\in E$, But to apply Ergoroff theorem I need to prove that $\mu(E)<\infty$ or $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$.
I know by the Dominated convergence theorem that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int |f_n-f| d\mu=0$ but I cannot see how shall I prove from there that $\mu(E)$ or $\mu(\Omega)$ are limited.

**Question:**

Can someone provide me any help?

Thanks in advance!

Note:$f_n$ does not necessarily converge to $f$ uniformly. So the question is not a duplicate.

Comment: If $\lambda>0$ then $\mu(\{x:g(x)>\lambda\})<\infty$.

Comment: @Jakobian My question is not a duplicate. If you read carefully the exercise you find out $f_n$ does not necessarily converge to $f$ uniformly. However the answer you provide assumes $f_n$ to converge uniformly so it is not answering this question.

Comment: @PedroGomes no, it doesn't. It's exactly the answer to your question

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In order to apply Ergoroff I need to prove the measure of the domain where the function converges is finite. It is already assumed in the question when $f_n\to f$ a.e that $\mu(\{x:g(x)>\lambda\})=0$.

Comment: @Jakobian Can you explain why my argument is wrong?

Comment: @PedroGomes I believe that some things you have to figure out on your own, and why you're wrong is one of them

Comment: How do I know that you are pointing me in the right direction if you do not prove you are? Does it not sound like an authority fallacy?

Comment: @PedroGomes don't be so stubborn, and read with care what's in the duplicate... not that hard, is it

Comment: No, the question certainly does not say that $\mu(\{x:g(x)>\lambda\})=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a bigger hint. Let $$E_k=\{x:g(x)>1/k\}.$$Since $\mu(E_k)<\infty$, Egoroff shows that there exists $S_k\subset E_k$ such that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $E_k\setminus S_k$ and $$\mu(S_k)<\epsilon/2^k.$$

So if $S=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty S_k$ then $\mu(S)<\epsilon$. And it's possible to prove that $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X\setminus S$. (There's still something to be proved in that last sentence, it's not quite just trivial by definition. Hint: So far we haven't used the fact that $|f_n|\le g$.)

Comment: Is it not $E_k=\{x:g(x)<1/k\}$. $S_k$ is subset of the set where $f_n$ converges to $f$? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: $E_k$ is not what you say it is. So I don't know whether you're asking about $E_k$ or about $\{x:g(x)<1/k\}$. But in either case: So what?